# php - Explode array into a key->value array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following string:

> Name_Location_Telephone_break_Name_Location_Telephone_break_Name_Location_Telephone_break_Name_Location_Telephone_break_

I got this from a cURL of an HTML page using DOM.

My final result must be a JSON file like:

```
Shop 1: { name: "example", location: "example", telephone: "0123"}
Shop 2: { name: "example", location: "example", telephone: "0123"}
```

But I know that first I have to split the string, I tried this

```
$shops = explode("break",$result);
$values = array();

foreach ($shops as $shop) {
    $values = explode("_", $shop);
    foreach($values as $value) {
        $name = $value[0];
        $location = $value[1];
        $tel = $value[2];
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Can anybody help me?

Comment: I think you should make your question with a better look, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

You're exploding on the wrong value:

```
Name_Location_Telephone_break_Name_Location_Telephone etc...
```

will become an array:

```
0 => 'Name_Location_Telephone_'
1 => '_Name_Location_Telephone_'
2 => '_Name_Location_Telephone_'
etc...
```

when you explode these, the first one will have `Name` at index `0`, but then at index `1` for all subsequent explodes.

You should be exploding on `_break_` instead.

If you'd done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($shops)` and `var_dump($values)`, you'd have seen how things shift around.

Answer (score 1):

1) Your first explode keeps some trimming underscore.

2) You have to use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php) method to transform your array to json data

A example that you can do

```
$result = "Name_Location_Telephone_break_Name_Location_Telephone_break_Name_Location_Telephone_break_Name_Location_Telephone_break_";
$shops = explode("_break_",$result);

foreach($shops as $key => $shop) {
    $res["Shop ".$key] = explode('_', $shop);
}

$jsonData = json_encode($res);
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

That's not exactly how you write the foreach. It differs from Java.
Checkout : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php for examples, and don't hesitate to do so from now on (thei PHP API is very good)

Answer (score 0):

you are almost close to your required result. try following

```
 $shops = explode("_break_",$result);
 $jsonArray = array();
 foreach ($shops as $shop){
     // three elements are same in response no need to worry just explode in array of three elements.
  $value = explode("_", $shop); 
   // assign prepared array or print it according to your business logic.
   $jsonArray[] = array ('name'=>$value[0], 'location'=>$value[1], 'telephone'=>$value[2]); 
 }
 //here you can encode your final multi dimensional array to json string.
echo json_encode($jsonArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

After first explode you need to trim the '_' at the last of string in the $shops array.

```
<?php
    $result = "Name_Location_Telephone_break_Name_Location_Telephone_break_Name_Location_Telephone_break_Name_Location_Telephone";
    $shops = explode("break",$result);
    echo json_encode($shops)."\n";
    $values = array();
    foreach ($shops as $shop){
        $values = explode("_", trim($shop, '_'));
        echo json_encode($values)."\n";
        $name = $values[0];
        $location = $values[1];
        $tel = $values[2];
        echo $name."\n";
    }
?>
```

and the result is,

```
["Name_Location_Telephone_","_Name_Location_Telephone_","_Name_Location_Telephone_","_Name_Location_Telephone"]
["Name","Location","Telephone"]
Name
["Name","Location","Telephone"]
Name
["Name","Location","Telephone"]
Name
["Name","Location","Telephone"]
Name
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because your first explode keeps some trimming underscore.

either do

```
$shops = explode("_break_",$result);
```

or

```
$shops = trim(explode("break",$result), "_");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = "Name_Location_Telephone_break_Name_Location_Telephone_break_Name_Location_Telephone_break_Name_Location_Telephone";

$shops = explode("_break_",$result);
$results = array();
$index = 1;

foreach ($shops as $shop) {
    $values = explode("_", $shop);

    $results["Shop $index"] = [
        'name' => $values[0],
        'location' => $values[1],
        'telephone' => $values[2],
    ];

    $index++;
}

print_r($results);
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [Shop 1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name
            [location] => Location
            [telephone] => Telephone
        )

    [Shop 2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name
            [location] => Location
            [telephone] => Telephone
        )

    [Shop 3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name
            [location] => Location
            [telephone] => Telephone
        )

    [Shop 4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name
            [location] => Location
            [telephone] => Telephone
        )

)
```

You had spare "_" after first `explode` by only `break`, that's why the result may became wrong.